# How do I combine javascript variables into a object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

**I need to combine all variables in one object:**

```
$.get("https://www.virginmegastore.ae/en/gaming/playstation/playstation-games/sonic-forces---ps4/p/714792", function (data) {
    var productNamePost=$("[name='productNamePost']").val();
    var productCodePost=$("[name='productCodePost']").val();
    var bg = $('.pdp_image-carousel-image.js-zoomImage-mobile').css('background-image');
    var productPrice=$(".price__container > .price__value > .price__number").text();
    var url      = window.location.href;   

    console.log(url);
});
```

Sorry the question was unclear,i was need this

```
let obj = Object.assign({},var)
```

I also need to run the code when the button clicked

```
 $.get("https://www.virginmegastore.ae/en/gaming/playstation/playstation-games/sonic-forces---ps4/p/714792", function (data) {    
 $("#addToCartForm > #addToCartButton").click(function(){ 
         var productNamePost=$("[name='productNamePost']").val();
         var productCodePost=$("[name='productCodePost']").val();
         var bg = $('.pdp_image-carousel-image.js-zoomImage-mobile').css('background-image');
         var productPrice=$(".price__container > .price__value > .price__number").text();
         var url      = window.location.href;   
        let obj = Object.assign({}, [productNamePost, productCodePost, bg, productPrice, url]);
        console.log(obj)});

});
```

but i got below error when i clicked the button:

[image]

Comment: `var o = { productNamePost:$("[name='productNamePost']").val(), productCodePost:$("[name='productCodePost']").val() };`

Comment: What have you tried and what was the problem? Creating objects is one of the most basic and most widely used code structures in javascript..

Comment: You haven't told use information like, what variables shall be combines and maybe the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let obj = Object.assign({}, [
   productNamePost: $("[name='productNamePost']").val(), 
   productCodePost: $("[name='productCodePost']").val(), 
   bg: $('.pdp_image-carousel-image.js-zoomImage-mobile').css('background-image'), 
   productPrice: $(".price__container > .price__value > .price__number").text(), 
   url: window.location.href
]);
```

This will create an object array with all your variables. Read more about `Object.assign()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: thank you dear @MeesEgberts, i has another question also

Comment: What is your other question? @Alaa

Comment: I updated the question,i need to output the results after button clicked.@MeesEgberts

Comment: If you have a new question, you should ask the new question, don't "continue" in this question

Comment: It says that you are trying to work with a variable that doesn't exist so you need to work with the variable that you just created @Alaa

Comment: `val is not defined` - did you miss `()` on `.val()` ?

Comment: i tried to print any thing and the error is still,like: $("#addToCartForm > #addToCartButton").on('click',function(){ 
        console.log("test")});
});    @MeesEgberts

Comment: @Alaa that doesn't look like an error. Please add the entire function to your question so I can take a look!

Comment: $.get("https://www.virginmegastore.ae/en/gaming/playstation/playstation-games/sonic-forces---ps4/p/714792", function (data) {   
 $("#addToCartForm").on("click",function(){ 
        console.log("test")});
}); 
@MeesEgberts

Comment: You should put the `$.get("...")` in the `click` not the `click` in the  `$.get("...")`

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
var newObj = {
  "productNamePost": $("[name='productNamePost']").val(),
  "productCodePost": $("[name='productCodePost']").val(),
  "variable_name": variable_value
}
```